# Position div inside a image (responsive)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a problem (obviously). 
I have to position a element to be always on the right side of a image.
But I can't use the img-Tag as a container.
Also I'm using bootstrap, which makes it impossible to set a fixed width for the container.

Small example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzd7maqq/)

```
<div id="container" class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="positioning">
      Some Text
  </div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/eeeeee" />
</div>
```

I hope that is understandable

**EDIT:**
Basically I want the image to behave like a container, without using "background-image"

Comment: Something similar to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzd7maqq/1/)?

Comment: Do you need to use an img tag or could you set the background of the div to the image?

Comment: @lukevp think you'd have to use the image tag to make the div keep the height of the image when resized

Comment: This needs more explanation. There's too many ways to interpret this.

Comment: @Last1Here unfortionally no, the Element is positioned at the container, resize the window a little bit

Comment: @lukevp I can use background-images but I want to avoid using inline-style, the src of the img will be stored in a variable

Comment: @gotta_ask see revised answer below

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrap the image and the caption in a div with `position: relative` like in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzd7maqq/6/)

**html**

```
<div id="container" class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="img-container">
        <div class="positioning">
            Some Text
        </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/eeeeee" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-lg-3{
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 230px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
}
.col-lg-3 img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.img-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.positioning{
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 22px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

Comment: You should upvote this guy's answer if you accepted it and liked it!  I upvoted as well since it was the accepted answer and you are satisfied with it.

Comment: Well, I can't upvote atm, I don't have enough reputation to do that now x)

Answer (score 3):

I think the `<figure>` tag is the best solution here.

Here's an exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/mzd7maqq/7/

Comment: Same problem with the div, the "Some Text" element gets positioned to the figure, resize the window a bit.

Comment: In that case just display the `<figure>` as a inline-block

[http://jsfiddle.net/mzd7maqq/7/]

It's the same answer as @Last1Here but it's HTML5 friendly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the float property and set it to right.

```
style="float:right";
```

Comment: Unfortunaly not that simple, float positions it yet again to the wrong container

Answer (score 0):

An absolutely positioned element will always be positioned relating to it's parent that has 'position: relative'. Here is a good example http://learnlayout.com/position.html

So if you wrap the  and the content inside a div and position it relatively, then you can position the content absolutely inside it. Then, you just need to make the  display: block; and width 100% so the  will fill the whole container.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.container img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.container .content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kbzvyjy9/

Hope that solves your issue.